# Get a gitlab-ci pipeline execution status with curl in jenkins pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, curl, jq, gitlab-ci-runner

In my jenkins pipeline, I have a stage that should trigger a gitlab ci pipeline with curl, it works well. Now I want to send a second curl command to ask gitlab api for the status of last pipeline (Iam looking for status: success) to move to next jenkins pipeline stage

this is my curl command:

```
stage('Get Pipeline Status') {
    steps {
        script {
            // Run a curl command to get pipeline details from GitLab
            def pipelineStatus = sh(
                script: "curl --insecure --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-token' https://mygitlab.domain/api/v4/projects/229/pipelines/latest",
                returnStatus: true)//.trim()                                      

            def status = sh(script: """
                echo "'$pipelineStatus' | jq -r '.status'", returnStatus: true)//.trim()
            
            if (status == 'success') {
                echo "Pipeline succeeded"
            } else {
                echo "Pipeline did not succeed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when use .trim() I get this error (so I comment it):

```
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 69e61b29-b180-44e9-a18f-b06b1a84f99a
10:36:18  hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.trim() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
10:36:18  Possible solutions: wait(), grep(), wait(long), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), div(java.lang.Number)
```

I can retreive the output result from gitlab with my curl command like:

```
{"id":1664,"iid":19,"project_id":229,"sha":"9e70fd49d14e86ccd6091addf394ded51d22ab50","ref":"main","status":"success","source":"trigger","created_at":"2023-11-06T15:41:36.238Z","updated_at":"2023-11-06T15:41:38.854Z","web_url":"https://mygitlab.domain/test-ci/-/pipelines/1664","before_sha":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","tag":false,"yaml_errors":null,"user":{"id":98,"username":"907802","name":"myname","state":"active","locked":false,"avatar_url":"https://mygitlab.domain/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/98/avatar.png","web_url":"https://mygitlab.domain/907802"},"started_at":"2023-11-06T15:41:37.695Z","finished_at":"2023-11-06T15:41:38.841Z","committed_at":null,"duration":1,"queued_duration":1,"coverage":null,"detailed_status":{"icon":"status_success","text":"Passed","label":"passed","group":"success","tooltip":"passed","has_details":false,"details_path":"/907802/test-ci/-/pipelines/1664","illustration":null,"favicon":"/assets/ci_favicons/favicon_status_success-8451333011eee8ce9f2ab25dc487fe24a8758c694827a582f17f42b0a90446a2.png"},"name":null}
```

But I want to get just "status":"success" part to make a test, if status=success then I execute the next jenkins pipeline stage. but what I made with "jq" don't work and I think that the "echo "$pipelineStatus'" is equal to "0" !

this is the error:

```
10:36:18  [Pipeline] sh
10:36:18  + echo 0
10:36:18  + jq -r status
10:36:18  jq: error: status/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
10:36:18  status
10:36:18  jq: 1 compile error
```

How can I do it correctly, I take all working solutions , the goal is to have a report for my first curl command to know that my gitlab ci pipeline is executed correctly to move to next stage.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The line starting with `echo "$pipelineStatus'` has weird quotings (including an odd number of `'` quotes).

Comment: thanks pmf I add the ' missed, itsn't the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have your response from api in JSON format, the easiest way is to parse the response, and get value of `status` key. For this, you will need to install Pipeline Utility Steps plugin to Jenkins.

```
stage('Get Pipeline Status') {
    steps {
        script {
            // Run a curl command to get pipeline details from GitLab
            def pipelineResponse = sh(
                script: "curl --insecure --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-token' https://mygitlab.domain/api/v4/projects/229/pipelines/latest",
                returnStatus: true)

            def jsonResponse = readJSON text: pipelineResponse
            def status = jsonResponse['status']

            if (status == 'success') {
                echo "Pipeline succeeded"
            } else {
                echo "Pipeline did not succeed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```